# 'Warning:Attempt to present ^ on UINavigationController: 0x7d090c00 while a presentation is in progress!'on using the UIPopoverPresentationController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm getting warning like this 'Warning:Attempt to present KKContactTypeTableViewController: 0x7b6f2170 on UINavigationController: 0x7d090c00 while a presentation is in progress!'on using the UIPopoverPresentationController.Like this at viewController A for pushing a UIPopoverPresentationController:

```
 -(void)contactTypePopView{
        _contactTypePopController = [[KKContactTypeTableViewController alloc] init];
        _contactTypePopController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
        //[self presentViewController:_contactTypePopController animated:YES completion:nil];
        [self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:_contactTypePopController animated:YES completion:nil];
        UIPopoverPresentationController *popPresent = [_contactTypePopController popoverPresentationController];
        popPresent.delegate = self;
        popPresent.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft;
        popPresent.sourceView = self.contaxt_type;
        popPresent.sourceRect = self.contaxt_type.bounds;


    }
```

and dismiss viewController at KKContactTypeTableViewController like this:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    KKContactTpye *contactType = self.contactTypes[indexPath.row];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ContactType" object:nil userInfo:@{@"ContactTypeName":contactType.Name,@"ContactTypeId":contactType.ID}];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

and then I push viewController A to B the warning appeared while UIPopoverPresentationController at viewController A is also brought!I searched on Internet and read questions about this but not got any answer.please give a better soluton thanks in advance!

Comment: Try [self.view.window.rootViewController.presentingViewController presentViewController:_contactTypePopController animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: Also I would not recommend fetching rootViewController when presenting. Instead if the controller has UINavigationController, you can present like [self.navigationController.presentingViewController presentViewController:_contactTypePopController animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: @Varun I do it as you said but it can't push a UIPopoverPresentationController now while the way I did can,then I try [self.navigationController presentViewController:_contactTypePopController animated:YES completion:nil];it's ok.Thanks!